# Uniqueness of LASSO

Tags: lasso, regularization

I gather the LASSO estimator is unique when the columns of predictor matrix $X$ are in general position, as mentioned [here](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Eryantibs/papers/lassounique.pdf).

What is a specific example of predictor matrix $X$ that does not obey this condition that would induce LASSO to be nonunique?

Comment: Does the paper you cite not offer an example?

Comment: They use the term "general position" to mean something highly specific to the LARS algorithm.  Any predictor matrix $\boldsymbol{X}$ can be used in a LASSO, just like any predictor matrix can be used in linear regression.  The LARS algorithm will converge to its optimal and unique solution